# How do I do a DELETE in MySQL with NOT IN?

Tags: mysql

I'm getting this error when running the code:

> Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'details' for update
>   in FROM clause

```
DELETE FROM details WHERE detail NOT IN 
(
    SELECT detail 
    FROM user_details
    JOIN data ON user_details.data_iddata = data.iddata
    JOIN details ON details.iddetails = data.details_iddetails
)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Best answer in the dupe is the third one down http://stackoverflow.com/a/9843719/73226

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a system handy, but I think the problem is that you can reference the same table in a subquery as the main one you are deleting from. I.e. it doesn't like `JOIN details ON details.iddetails = data.details_iddetails` in the subquery because that's in the main select clause.

One workaround is to create a temp table, insert the records you are interested in into it, and then find your set from a join off of that.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to do a DELETE from a table **while** you're doing a SELECT from it.

In order to get this to work, make a list from your SELECT query and put its results in the parentheses.

If you aren't doing this in an external script, you should define a view that will give you the desired SELECT output.